# Multi dimensional associative array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, associative-array

I need some guide to associative array below, how do i access or retrieve specified value,for example the height under the student_name "Kevin" in the student_details in JSON format.

```
<?php
$college=[
    'college_id' => '123',
    'student_details'=> [
        'student_name'=>[
            'Kevin'=> [
                'height'=>'170',
                'weight'=>'65',
            ],
            'Daniel'=> [
                'height'=>'170',
                'weight'=>'65',
            ] ,
            'Paul'=> [
                'height'=>'179',
                'weight'=>'70',
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
echo json_encode($college);
?>
```

Comment: Why would you deal try to deal with JSON in PHP?  You should only be manipulating the array and converting to JSON for output.

Comment: if i need to pass this array in JSON encode to another page, how should i access the value in it ?

Comment: Is another page a PHP or JavaScript? If PHP so you can use `json_decode()`

Comment: PHP , after i used the json decode, how i should i access the specified data as i mentioned above,  for example the height under the student_name "Kevin" in the student_details

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `$array = json_decode($json, true);`

```
<?php
echo $array['student_details']['student_name']['Kevin']['height'];
?>
```

Or if you use `$object = json_decode($json);`

```
<?php
echo $object->student_details->student_name->Kevin->height;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks bro, it helps a lot